# Реализовать foreach для обобщенного класса

Tags: c#

Есть класс - реализация очереди через List

```
class CCQueue<T>
{
    private LinkedList<T> _items = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        _items.AddFirst(value);

    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (_items.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Queue Empty");
        }

        T last = _items.Last.Value;

        _items.RemoveLast();

        return last;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (_items.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Queue is empty");
        }

        return _items.Last.Value;
    }
}
```

Есть класс-контейнер в котором CCQueue используется в качестве хранилища. Никак не пойму как реализовать foreach для класса контейнера.

```
class CСCol<T>
{
    private CСQueue<T> _queue;
}
```

Comment: Напишите как именно вы хотите использовать `foreach`, с примером кода

Comment: Перебор по экземпляру класса CCCol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще для использования `foreach` потребуется добавить в класс метод `GetEnumerator()` (можно реализовать интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`, но это не обязательно - `foreach` будет работать и так, но, например, Linq работает только с `IEnumerable<T>`).

Но так, как настоящая коллекция у вас скрыта внутри `CCQueue<T>`, то придется реализовать метод `GetEnumerator()` и в этом классе. В самом простейшем случае это может выглядеть вот так:

```
class CCQueue<T>
{
    ...

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _items.GetEnumerator();
}

class CСCol<T>
{
    ...

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _queue.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: А если реализовать интерфейс, то что необходимо еще?

Comment: Больше ничего, но придется реализовать так же и необобщенную версию, так как `IEnumerable<T>` реализует `IEnumerable`. Но обычно необобщенный метод реализуют просто как вызов обобщенного.

Comment: Кстати, студия может сама вам реализовать этот интерфейс в таких простых случаях: [скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkCH9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в класс `CCQueue<T>`, а также в класс контейнер (_items = объект очереди):

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (T item in _items)
    {
        // здесь какая-то логика
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var cccol = new CCCol<int>(); foreach (var item in cccol) ;` не скомпилируется ведь все равно после этого

Comment: А можно реализовать через yield return? Я в образовательных целях интересуюсь

Comment: @АндрейNOP почему?)

Comment: @AresGod, потому что в `CCCol` у вас нет метода `GetEnumerator()`. Вы не проверяете код, который выдаете? ;)

Comment: @e1s, можно, напишите метод так же как здесь, но в классе `CCCol`

Comment: @АндрейNOP прошу прощение) не посмотрел, автор уточнил вопрос) не правильно понял. Тогда да, нужно добавить этот код и в класс контейнер. Не нужно и реализовывать интерфейс, так как используется утиная типизация.